# How can we display toast or snack-bar in Flutter for web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How can we display a toast or snack-bar in flutter for web?
I have tried with many 3rd party lib but I couldn't achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the code that you tried? Did you have any error messages?

Answer (score 4):

Now yes, we can implement toasts, but with some restrictions.
Just tried simple [toast library](https://pub.dev/packages/toast) and [oktoast](https://pub.dev/packages/oktoast).
The last one works only with using showToastWidget method.

Answer (score 1):

use [okToast package](https://pub.dev/packages/oktoast#-readme-tab-),
with this package you just need to wrap the app or parent widget with ***OKToast*** and call ***showToast*** Method like this :

```
OKToast(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
           child: Container(
               color:Colors.white;
             child: RaisedButton(
               elevation: 20.0,
                  color:  Color(0xFFEE507A),

                child: Text("Show Toast"),
                onPressed: () { 
                             setState(() {
                       showToast(
                       " Toast has been succefully showing!! ",
                       position: ToastPosition.bottom,
                       backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEE507A),
                       radius: 13.0,
                      textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,color:Colors.white),
                       animationBuilder: Miui10AnimBuilder(),);
                             });


                }),
           ),
      )
    ),
  );
```